# I have an [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, sqlite, git-bash

I am doing a small project and I am using Python and SQLite3 with Sublime and Git-Bash.

I have created a database. I want to test to see the database

This is the request and the result I get from Git-Bash:

```
$ python databse.py
C:\Users\Pieter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe: can't open file 'databse.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The strange thing is the file I am asking for in my request is visible in the root directory.

Comment: And is your directory in git-bash set properly? Maybe try with full path and see if it will run, I would clearly say you are in incorrect dir

Comment: Is it possible you are misspelling your python file, i.e: database.py not databse.py? Run the following command and show the output: `ls -la` (note: this lists all the files and the permissions in your folder). Also try `python ./databse.py` to see if it makes any difference.